# sbt-assembly tasks don't display in sbt interactive mode

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm using sbt 1.0.1 and I've configured the sbt-assembly plugin (0.14.5) as per [its GitHub README](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/README.md).

When I run `$ sbt` (interactive mode) and run `> tasks`, none of the assembly tasks are displayed.

However, when I run `> help assembly` , I see its description (`Builds a deployable fat jar.`).

What am I doing wrong?

Is this a bug?

Am I missing an import statement in my `build.sbt`? (Not according to the Setup instructions in the current sbt-assembly README.)

Is there another command I have to run in order to see the sbt-assembly tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer using `> help tasks`. (Ergo, boneheaded question!)

Adding the flag `-V` to `tasks` `displays all tasks`. (That's simple enough.)

Enigmatically, the flag `-v` apparently `Displays additional tasks. More 'v's increase the number of tasks displayed.` Okay, fine, but using what logic? And how did sbt determine its original (apparently) arbitrarily restricted list of tasks?

I suppose I could simply delete this question as an embarrassing 'newbie' thing to ask. But I find that despite a considerable amount of documentation on sbt that exists (as of 2017), very little of it succeeds at communicating a either a conception of the entire system, or notion of how to use its various pieces to orchestrate your own build task.

So if this saves anyone any time at all learning sbt, I'll be pleased.